# Berks: Unable to satisfy constraints on package , which does not exist,

Tags: chef-infra, ohai-gem, berksfile

I have a very small example.  1 cookbook with 1 recipe and 1 ohai plugin file but getting errors running berks/berks install or converging when running kitchen

I do have the ohai gems installed:

```
chefspec-ohai (0.2.0)
ohai (14.2.0)
```

the plugin is in ./files/default/apache_modules.rb:

```
Ohai.plugin :Apache do
  provides 'apache/modules'

  collect_data :default do
    apache(Mash.new)
    modules_cmd = shell_out('apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES')
    apache[:modules] = modules_cmd.stdout
  end
end
```

the error is:

```
Unable to satisfy constraints on package , which does not exist, due to solution constraint (apache = 0.1.0). Solution constraints that may result in a constraint on : [(apache = 0.1.0) -> ( >= 0.0.0)]
Missing artifacts:
Demand that cannot be met: (apache = 0.1.0)
```

Notice on the first line there is a space between package and the comma. So I'm at a loss as to what package it is complaining about.

my cookbook is named apache and has 1 recipe default.rb:

```
package 'httpd'

service 'httpd' do
  action [:start, :enable]
end
```

metadata.rb:

```
name 'apache'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'All Rights Reserved'
description 'Installs/Configures apache'
long_description 'Installs/Configures apache'
version '0.1.0'
depends ohai
```

Berksfile:

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
metadata
```

my Berksfile and metadata.rb are both in the cookbooks/apache dir

Suggestions?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `depends "ohai"`, it has to be a string.